# Path() - Smart colored segments

Tags: java, android, graphics, maps, android-mapview

**Background**

I´m developing an application that displays a path over a map (Google maps and OpenStreet maps). Bellow an output example:

[image: Path]

To draw the above path I´m using the following approach:

```
private void drawWithoutElevation(Canvas canvas, Projection projection){
    if(rebuildRequired)
        pathBuild();
    else{ //check if path need to be offset
        if(offsetRequired){
            path.offset(offset.x, offset.y);
        }
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint); 
}
```

The approach above takes about 1.5ms to draw 10.000 points, which is acceptable.

However, I also want to show the path using different colors depending on the point altitude. Bellow an output example:

[image: Path 2]

As I couldn't find a way to define different color per path segment, I've tried the following approaches:

**Approach 1**

The most obvious solution, using a `canvas.drawLine()` between each point in the path. Example bellow:

```
private void drawWithElevation(Canvas canvas, Projection projection){
    for(int i=1; i<geoArrList.size(); i++){
            paint.setColor(geoArrList.get(i));
            canvas.drawLine(pPrev.x, pPrev.y, p1.x, p1.y, paint);
            pPrev.set(p1.x, p1.y);
        }
    }
}
```

This results in a very disappointing time of about 80ms for the same 10.000 points.

**Approach 2**

Segment the altitude in discrete steps, and build a list of `Path` objects, one per altitude segment change. Code example below:

```
private void drawWithElevation(Canvas canvas, Projection projection){
    if(rebuildRequired)
        pathBuild();
    for(int i=0; i<pathSegments.size(); i++){
        if(needOffset){
            pathSegments.get(i).path.offset(offsetX, offsetY);
        }
        paint.setColor(pathSegments.get(i).color);
        canvas.drawPath(pathSegments.get(i).path, paint); 
    }
}
```

This results in a less disappointing time of about 5ms for the same 10.000 points.

**Question**

Although the last approach shows a significant improvement, compared to the first one, I would like to further improve it.

Is there any other approach that could be used to draw the path with different color per segment in a more efficient way (speed and/or memory usage)?

Thanks for your time and your help.

Comment: 5ms is 200 fps. Are you sure you _need_ to improve the performance? If you want it run faster because you're going to plot e.g. 100k points, maybe it's time to reduce the number of points, provided that it's a smartphone screen, not a 4K screen?

Comment: Thanks @9000, you have a good point there... The driver for trying to improve it, is that the user can add several paths at same time, besides some other overlays (compass, markers, current location, etc.). May be I´ll need to live with that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the source for MyTracks by google, that may lead to some inspiration